# Flickr API returns less images

Tags: flickr, phpflickr, flickrj

I am trying to download Flickr [public domain images](https://www.flickr.com/creativecommons/) ([license code: 9,10](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.licenses.getInfo.html)). On the web I see there are more than 10M images however I get around 640k images when I use the fickr api. Below is my simple code.
Am i missing any filter or using any filter in wrong way?

[image]

```
from flickrapi import FlickrAPI
import xml

flickr = FlickrAPI(
    'access_key', 'secret_key')

# All the extra data that I want to have
extras = 'license,geo,description,url_o,height_o,width_o,machine_tags'

photos = flickr.photos.search(
    per_page=5,  # Number of results per page
    license='9,10',  # Attribution Licenses
    extras=extras,
    content_types=0,
    is_commons=True,
    privacy_filter=1,  # public photos
)

print(xml.etree.ElementTree.dump(photos))
```

Output:

```
<rsp stat="ok">
<photos page="1" pages="128276" perpage="5" total="641377">
    <photo accuracy="0" context="0" farm="9" height_o="2790" id="29533458786" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" latitude="0" license="7" longitude="0" machine_tags="" owner="44494372@N05" secret="815e410919" server="8796" title="President Kennedy - We Choose to Go to the Moon" url_o="https://live.staticflickr.com/8796/29533458786_b2566630f3_o.jpg" width_o="4032">
        <description>Speech at Rice University Stadium in Houston, Texas, President Kennedy standing at lectern. Delivered, &amp;quot;Address at Rice University on the Nation's Space Effort&amp;quot; - a speech famed for the line &amp;quot;We Choose to Go to the Moon, and do the other things, not because they are easy, but because they are hard.&amp;quot;


Image Number: s62-05616
Date: September 12, 1962</description>
    </photo>
    <photo accuracy="0" context="0" farm="8" height_o="3000" id="16188673307" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" latitude="0" license="7" longitude="0" machine_tags="" owner="44494372@N05" secret="9414d21999" server="7357" title="Zero Gravity Facility" url_o="https://live.staticflickr.com/7357/16188673307_e2f8cd50ed_o.jpg" width_o="2400">
        <description>Zero Gravity Facility at Lewis Research Center, now known as John H. Glenn Research Center at Lewis Field. This is a tunnel view looking up from level 5. This tower drops 460 feet and allows scientists 5.18 seconds of micro-gravity. By comparison, the Washington Monument is 555 feet tall. 

Image Number: C1966-3680 
Date: September 12, 1966</description>
    </photo>
    <photo accuracy="0" context="0" farm="9" height_o="2400" id="7584790398" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" latitude="0" license="7" longitude="0" machine_tags="" owner="44494372@N05" secret="07a6efc6fb" server="8429" title="NACA Physicist Studying Alpha Rays" url_o="https://live.staticflickr.com/8429/7584790398_a885ed1939_o.jpg" width_o="3000">
        <description>&lt;b&gt;Description:&lt;/b&gt; (September 12, 1957) NACA Physicist studying Alpha Rays in a continuous cloud chamber. A cloud chamber is used by Lewis scientists to obtain information aimed at minimizing undesirable effects of radiation on nuclear-powered aircraft components. Here, alpha particles from a polonium source emit in a flower-like pattern at the cloud chamber's center. The particles are made visible by means of alcohol vapor diffusing from an area at room temperature to an area at minus -78 deg. Centigrade. Nuclear-powered aircraft were never developed and aircraft nuclear propulsion systems were canceled in the early 1960's.

&lt;b&gt;Center:&lt;/b&gt; GRC   
&lt;b&gt;Image # :&lt;/b&gt; C1957-45925 </description>
    </photo>
    <photo accuracy="16" context="0" farm="66" geo_is_contact="0" geo_is_family="0" geo_is_friend="0" geo_is_public="1" height_o="2000" id="53181577260" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" latitude="54.325627" license="7" longitude="-8.493418" machine_tags="" owner="47290943@N03" place_id="" secret="7c26fe8922" server="65535" title="Fabled in song and in story - Drumcliffe Churchyard" url_o="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/53181577260_6dda823c5b_o.jpg" width_o="2405" woeid="2964618">
        <description>
No doubt there's many a rustic man and woman in the Churchyard at Drumcliffe but most people will associate it with a Nobel Prize winning poet and his cryptic epitaph.  That are in County Sligo is absolutely heavenly and anyone who has ever contemplated a final resting place would be tempted to join him there!

Photographer: &lt;b&gt;Robert French&lt;/b&gt;

Collection: &lt;b&gt;&lt;a href="http://catalogue.nli.ie/Collection/vtls000313414" rel="noreferrer nofollow"&gt;Lawrence Photograph Collection&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/b&gt;

Date: Circa 1865 - 1914

NLI Ref:  &lt;b&gt;&lt;a href="https://catalogue.nli.ie/Record/vtls000330178" rel="noreferrer nofollow"&gt;L_IMP_0937&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/b&gt;

You can also view this image, and many thousands of others, on the NLI’s catalogue at &lt;a href="http://catalogue.nli.ie" rel="noreferrer nofollow"&gt;catalogue.nli.ie&lt;/a&gt;

</description>
    </photo>
    <photo accuracy="0" context="0" farm="66" height_o="1450" id="53179767602" isfamily="0" isfriend="0" ispublic="1" latitude="0" license="7" longitude="0" machine_tags="" owner="49487266@N07" secret="e29da7cbff" server="65535" title="23_0010928 Convair Negative Image" url_o="https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/53179767602_8d4cee2046_o.jpg" width_o="1600">
        <description>86446885 :Piction ID--Wires attached to cylindrical structure---Please tag these photos so information can be recorded.---- Digitization of this image made possible by a grant from NEH: &lt;a href="https://sandiegoairandspace.org/research/project/nehfunded" rel="noreferrer nofollow"&gt;NEH and the San Diego Air and Space Museum &lt;/a&gt;</description>
    </photo>
</photos>
</rsp>
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```